# Property 'index' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
if (this.props.children) {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>, {
                index: child.props.index || i // <-- line that causes error
            });
        }
        return child;
    });
}
```

Gives compile error `error TS2339: Property 'index' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Why? How to fix?

Comment: Are you sure the child has props? Can you try checking the prop is set? Something like `index: child.props ? child.props.index : i`

Comment: @Stretch0 That just gives the same error.

Comment: Try `child.props['index']` instead

Comment: @Madhavan.V Thanks, that worked! Post it as an answer, and I'll mark it:) Still very confused what's causing this though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
child.props['index']
```

Note:
    In `typescript` you can not access indexed properties using the dot notation. So it will give compile time error

Comment: Thanks again. Do you have a link to some doc page explaining this in more detail?

Comment: I have read this somewhere, but I'm not sure where. definitely I'll update here once I got this. :)